# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Int32)'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

MVC5 / EF 6

In my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectPlayer", (SelectList)ViewBag.Players, "Select Player", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And in my Controller:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(mySession.Format) == 4)
{
    List<Int32> teamDrawPIDs = new List<Int32>();
    List<TeamDraw> teamDrawPlayers;
    teamDrawPlayers = entityDB.TeamDraws.Where(t => t.TID == TID).ToList();

    foreach (TeamDraw tPlayer in teamDrawPlayers)
    {
        teamDrawPIDs.Add(tPlayer.PID);
    }

    // only get players in TeamDraw
    ViewBag.Players = new SelectList(entityDB.Players.Where(t => (teamDrawPIDs.IndexOf(t.PID) != -1)).OrderBy(p => p.Last), "PID", "selectListName");
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Players = new SelectList(entityDB.Players.OrderBy(p => p.Last), "PID", "selectListName");
}
```

When `mySession.Format` is not 4, this all works fine. however whenever it Is 4, and my `ViewBag.Players` is created from only `ID`'s in `teamDrawPIDs` and I get this error (on the view page, controller is fine):

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Int32)'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error, the expression using `IndexOf()` can't be translated into `Sql`. You can try something more Sql Friendly, such as:

```
entityDB.Players.Where(t => teamDrawPIDs.Contains(t.PID))
                .OrderBy(p => p.Last)
```

You can also use some linq to eliminate the for-each, e.g. in one step:

```
var teamDrawPIDs = teamDrawPlayers.Select(tp => tp.PID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! i still dont entirely understand the difference but your snipped solved it.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, entity framework will try to re-parse the expression predicate / filter passed in `.Where()` as a Sql statement. Unfortunately, not everything you pass in the predicate can be dissected, such as the use of `IndexOf` to see whether a field exists. However, doing this via `.Contains` will be parsable into something similar to a `SQL IN('x', 'y')` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Frameworrk not support direct cast.So is best practice at my personl advice setup a variable with the value that we will use a filter in order to prevent this type of issue.